# Is 9.5 x 3 a standard whole-house water filter cartridge size?

Tags: water, filter

A while ago we had a whole house water filter installed, and I've let it go a bit too long before replacing the cartridge. Now I want to, but there are no markings on the filter housing to help me select a replacement. I shut the water off and removed the old cartridge. It is 9.5" tall and 3" in diameter. I see a lot of cartridges on Amazon that are 10 x 2.5. Is that a match?

Comment: Related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/222191/how-to-identify-a-whole-house-water-filter-type?rq=1

Comment: Do you know the manufacturer of the water filter? They would certainly be the expert on what to use as a replacement filter.

Comment: Alas, there are no markings anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a chance and got the "standard" size GE basic filter and it appears to fit and work just fine. So I guess this is a standard size (or close enough).